# Missing node module while using graphql in TypeScript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I tried using the @types/graphql package with [TypeScript Node Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter#typescript-node-starter) and had problems

```
node_modules//subscription/subscribe.d.ts(17,4): error TS2314: Generic type AsyncIterator<T, E>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules//subscription/subscribe.d.ts(29,4): error TS2304: Cannot find name AsyncIterable'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes typings have errors, possibly due to newer TS versions catching more errors. Generally you still get sensible type data from them. To ignore errors in typings, you can add `"skipLibCheck": true` to your `tsconfig.json`.